# Why are automatically handled comment flags not considered helpful?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, helpful-flags

Having flagged my fair share of accept rate comments, I noticed that while they result in automatic nuking of the comment in question, it seems they are not adding to the amount of comment flags "deemed helpful". Am I imagining things or is this indeed the case?

I would say that, if they result in nuking the comment and as such were appropriate (even if this is automatically determined by the system), they should be deemed helpful.

Admittedly a very minor issue and not terribly important (I don't even consider it a bug), but I thought I'd bring it up since I noticed it just now.

**NOTE:**
At the time of this update it does seem something has changed somewhere. The comment flag count now has caught up, and my helpful + declined score does equal the total number of comment flags.

Comment: I would say that the helpful flag should be set if the flag was helpful to a moderator (or other reviewer) - that is, it helped someone else with the manual moderation of the site.

Comment: My guess: to stop two person teams from gaming flagweight with no oversight and very little record afterwards.

Comment: @Oded Ah, "helpful to a moderator" might indeed be an explanation. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Is there even a "helpful" count for comment flags? Comment flags don't count for the "helpful flags" count that is relevant for the badges.

Comment: @Flexo There's not such thing as flagweight...ssshhhh

Comment: @DanielFischer [Why yes there is such a count](http://i.imgur.com/cLyuu.png)

Comment: Ah, okay. I've only ever flagged auto-nuked comments, so it just says "n comments flagged" there for me.

Comment: @Oded as far as I can tell, this is [meta-tag:status-completed], correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Status-NoRepro for me.

When I go to my profile page it shows ***N amount*** of helpful flags. When I click on that, it shows ***n amount*** of helpful flags under moderator attention flags. Then below that it shows ***n amount*** of deemed helpful flags under comment flags. Those two ***n's*** added together gives me the ***N amount*** of helpful flags.

Also, on each one of my auto-deleted comment flags, it shows ***helpful*** next to it in the flag history.

So yes, auto-nuked comment flags are helpful to me and you and more importantly, the unicorns.

Comment: Yeah... definitely necromancer

Comment: @iStimple I'm tempted to flag and get a helpful flag from 'accept' auto-nuking. How very meta.

Comment: It does seem indeed that something has been changed. Looking at my current counts, the helpful count has caught up. I guess some fix did happen somewhere.