# Comment flag limbo

Tags: bug, comments, flag-history

I flagged an "increase your accept rate" comment as "not constructive" a couple of days ago, and the comment disappeared as soon as my flag was raised. I assumed there were other similar flags on the comment, and mine triggered auto-deletion.

Then, I checked my flagging history and was surprised to see that flag wasn't deemed helpful nor declined. Now the total number of flagged comments does not correspond to the sum of the breakdown  below it, unlike what happens with my posts, spam and offensive flags.

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146298/why-are-automatically-handled-comment-flags-not-considered-helpful

Comment: @Bart, thanks for the link, I remembered that vaguely, but couldn't find it even on Google.