# What did happen with my two flags?

Tags: discussion, bug, comment-flags, flag-history

I'm not getting exactly what is happening here

[image]

You can see I had flagged `8` comments from that `4` are helpful and `2` are declined, but I'm not able to find what is the status of my other `2` flags?

**Update**

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history/132040#132040) I can see a `waiting for review` in flag history so with reference to [hims056's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156622/what-did-happen-with-my-two-flags#comment451155_156622) can't we have same status for comments flag?

Comment: [This is my comments stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGomD.png)

Comment: but [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history/132040#132040) I can see a `waiting for review` in flag history?

Comment: That is for quesion or answer's flag not comment's flag.

Comment: There was a time when the status was not recorded — that was a while ago now, but people who've been around for a while, like me on SO, have totals with a big gap (42 on flagged questions; 23 on flagged comments).  It isn't a critical statistic; don't fret.

Comment: Jarrod and I are moving where the flags are stored but it may take up to a few weeks as it's a *major* project - we'll be sure to look at this when we do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment flags, like comments, are second-class citizens. You are only shown statistics, not the actual comments or the status of flags still waiting for review.

Your statistics show that you flagged 8 comments; 4 of those flags were deemed helpful, 2 were declined and the remaining 2 have either not yet been handled *or* they have been handled automatically, and thus do not have a status any longer.

(<sub><sup>Note that veteran SO comment flaggers have another option: the comment flag system didn't track comment flags *at all* until those stats were implementented, so those of us who have been around long may have flags that were either helpful or declined but were not counted in the `helpful` or `declined` counters. They *are* counted in the total flag count for comments:</sup></sub>

[image: older flags were not recorded]).

Since comment flags don't get you anything anyway (other than a warm fuzzy feeling that you have made the site a better place), I wouldn't worry about this too much in any case.

Comment: This means *total flagged - (helpful+declined) = still to review* , is it? moreover can you just have a look at update part?

Comment: @hotveryspicy: That's answered by 'comment flags .. are second-class citizens'. That information is not given to us, so the answer, currently, is "no, we don't have that status information".

Comment: @hotveryspicy: And as animuson stated, automatically handled flags are also not marked as helpful or declined. They are just no longer waiting for review anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases where comment flags get dismissed **without a status being applied**. Most notably, comment flags which are automatically handled (such as flagging an "accept rate" comment) [do not get marked as helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146298). This causes your total number of comments flagged to increase without increasing either of your helpful or declined comment flags.

I'm sure a vast majority of users who participate in comment flagging don't have numbers which add up.